# Checking rails form data against key before saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm attempting to write an app that allows users to register different id numbers to their account through the use of a form.  The ids have their own model and the table is as follows:

```
mysql> show columns in hp_ids;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_string  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pin_number | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The id number is saved under `id_string`

The trick is that, in order to register an id, a user must enter its corresponding pin to prove that they have the right to register it..

**What I want to do is,** each time someone attempts to register a new id/pin combination, I would like to check it against a key of sorts to make sure that they have the right combination.  I figure I would create a new model called `IdKey` or something like that but I can't figure out how I would tell the controller to check the form values against this second model prior to saving them.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You could ,hypothetically, apply the same procedure done to passwords to this. Generate a hash value of the id/pin combination and save that; then take the user's input and generate a hash from those values in the same way, then compare the hash for equivalency. Barring that, can you simply do a lookup on the table using the user's input, something like `HpId.where(id_string: params[:id_string], pin_number: params[:pin_number])`?

Comment: @PaulRichter Thanks for the response!  I assume such a lookup would go into my controller?

Comment: Yes, or you can put it a method of the model (or even a scope if you want to be fancy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a [conditional](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation) or [custom](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) validation.

I may be misunderstanding your question, but is `pin_number` a preexisting value? If so, I'd guess it should exist in a different table (which could be queried during your custom validation).

Comment: Hi TK, thanks for your reply.  You have it right, the pin is a preexisting value.  I'll have a look through the custom validation and see if I can do something with it.  Do you know of any good documentation out there for this particular sort of custom validation?  Many thanks again.

Comment: Hello, if you haven't already, I'd check out the links in my answer (conditional and custom validation explanations from Guides: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html). From there I'd head for Google and SO...

Comment: Nailed it.  Thanks dude.